# PHP show files in a directory in a certain date/time period

Tags: php, perl

I am trying to work out the best way to search a file directory with PHP and return a list of files within a date period. The file names are time stamped, but using this method would require looping through every file to retrieve the results. There are over 80,000 files per folder. This is resource heavy.

Are there any built in functions to PHP to do this or what is the best to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:
Would it more efficient to call a back end script like perl, then return the results to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getFilesByTime($folder, $from, $to, $format){
  $contents = scandir($folder); $a = array();
  foreach($contents as $f){
    if(is_file($f)){
      $ft = filemtime($f);
      if($ft >= strtotime($from) && $ft <= strtotime($to))$a[$f] = date($format, $ft);
    }
  }
  return $a;
}
print_r(getFilesByTime('wherever', '10/15/2005', 'now', 'F d, Y H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I wanted to avoid loading the full file list, I was hoping it could be as light weight as possible. I take it there is no way to use file system index's with PHP?

Comment: if(is_file($f)) should be if(is_file($folder."/".$f))

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do without consuming lots of RAM (unless you have to read in all the files for some reason).  I've done this kind of software many times, and it works well.

Use `opendir` to open the directory you want to examine.

Then use `readdir` in a loop to read the files' names one by one. `readdir` handles the files in the same order as they're stored in the filesystem's directory object. This is helpful for a directory as large as the one you mention, because it won't attempt to sort the filenames. (There's another api called `scandir`. That one *does* sort the filenames; don't use it in your many-files application.)

Each time you call `readdir` it gives you the filename of the next file in the directory. Here's the documentation; the examples are helpful.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Once you have each filename, you can efficiently look up the file's various attributes with `stat`.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php  This will tell you useful stuff like the creation time, length, owner.

If you're on a *nix system (like BSD or Linux) you can very quickly move the file to a different directory *on the same file system* without copying it, by using `link` and then `unlink`.  If you just `unlink` it, that deletes it.

One thing to keep in mind here: you should treat the order in which `readdir` gives you back your file names as *formally unpredictable* or *random*. They aren't guaranteed to be in any given order. I've been caught by this, because remote (NFS) filesystems handled the order differently than local filesystems in a couple of environments I have used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it more efficient to call a back end script like perl, then return the results to PHP?

Comment: @JohnJ, no, PERL would have the same efficiency; you'd do all this the same way in PERL as PHP. Either way it will take time proportional to the number of files, and a constant amount of memory.